# How to create node when user submit values in webform and click submit?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

My website(D6) have "Quick Enquiry Form"(using webform) & i need to create a new node simultaneously when user click the submit button in webform.

How do i get values from the webform and insert the values to the node when user click the submit button.

Please suggest me how to do this!!

Comment: Instead of creating the "Quick Enquiry Form" as a webform, can you create it as a Content Type so it can be a node form that users fill out? That way the nodes get created automatically.

Comment: at the same time i have to send emails to admin

Comment: You can use the Rules module to easily send e-mails when content is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a custom module. The module will have two functions:

1. HOOK_form_alter - to add an additional submit function to the existing webform.
2. custom function - Custom function (called from HOOK_form_alter) to take the values from the submitted webform and create the node.

Before you create the module, you should use the core node module and CCK to create a content type that contains all of the same fields as the webform.

### HOOK_form_alter

In the example below, substitue the name of your module fir MODULENAME and the ID of your webform for XXX in the switch case. This function adds MODULENAME_create_node to your webform's submit function array. We will define MODULENAME_create_node below.

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'webform_client_form_XXX' :
    $first = array_shift($form['#submit']);
    array_unshift($form['#submit'], $first, 'MODULENAME_create_node');

    break;

  }
}
```

### MODULENAME_create_node

This is the main function that will create the node.

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_create_node() {
  // Load all of the data submitted via the webform into a keyed array ($data)
  $data = array();
  foreach ($form_state['values']['submitted_tree'] as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = $value;
  }

  // The node_save() function (called later in this function) call
  // node_access_check, which means that anonymous calls to this function will
  // not be successful. Top get around this, we load user1 while executing this
  // function, then restore the user back to the original state at the end of
  // the function.
  global $user;
  $original_user = $user;
  $user = user_load(1);

  // Initialize the new node with default stuff
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE';
  $node->created = time();
  $node->changed = $node->created;
  $node->status = 1;
  $node->promote = 0;
  $node->sticky = 0;
  $node->format = 1;
  $node->uid = $user->uid;

  // You'll need to customize this based on what you named your webform and CCK fields.
  // Remember that all of the webform data is available and stored in the $data array.
  $node->title = $data['title'];
  $node->field_myfield1[0]['value'] = $data['myfield1'];
  $node->field_myfield2[0]['value'] = $data['myfield2'];

  //Save the node
  node_save($node);

  //Set the user state back to the original
  $user = $original_user;

}
```

You'll also need to create an info file for your module. See Drupal's documentation on [writing info files](http://drupal.org/node/231036) if you're not familiar.

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for your answer. i am getting error message after submitting the form. "warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ". Can you please suggest me what i have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Bala - You need to pass the form and form_state to the custom function like so:

```
<?php
function MYMODULENAME_create_node($form, $form_state) {
   // ... above code
}
```

Otherwise the $form_state variable is empty and will throw the error you are experiencing.